# Inserting a column into a csv file using Python

Tags: python, csv

I have some csv files with about a dozen columns that needs another column inserted at a specific place between them all. The column can be empty or all the same for now, it just needs to be there.  I've checked a bunch of similar questions here but none of the answers are working for me. CSV is already imported.

```
new_col = 'SampleText'
with open(infile.csv, 'r') as f:
    with open('outfile.csv', 'w', newline='') as output:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter='|')
        for row in reader:
            new_row = ('|'.join(row[:6]) + new_col + '|'.join(row[7:]))
            writer.writerow([new_row])
```

The first line of the the output file is shown below. The new column is being put at the end of each line without a delimiter.

```
RCLT_TYPE|RCLC_NM|RCLCF_DATA_SORC|RCLF_NM|RCLF_DATA_TYPE_NM|RCLF_GRPABLE_IND|RT_LOV_IND|MULTI_SEGMENTATION_IND|RT_FLTBL_IND|RT_FLD_FRMT|History/Current|StorySampleText
```

Below is what the first line *should* look like, with the :

```
RCLT_TYPE|RCLC_NM|RCLCF_DATA_SORC|RCLF_NM|RCLF_DATA_TYPE_NM|RCLF_GRPABLE_IND|RT_LOV_IND|SampleText|MULTI_SEGMENTATION_IND|RT_FLTBL_IND|RT_FLD_FRMT|History/Current|Story
```

Any help with this is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

keeping close to your question, this should work:
Notice, I specified the delimiter for the file reader, thus each line is loaded as a list of fields. You can then easily insert values to this list and save it with a delimiter of your liking.

```
new_col = 'SampleText'
with open(path, 'r') as f:
    with open('outfile.csv', 'w', newline='') as output:
        reader = csv.reader(f,  delimiter=',')
        writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter='|')
        for row in reader:
            row.insert(7,new_col)
            new_row = '|'.join(row))
            writer.writerow(new_row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the library called pandas. So you can do

```
import pandas as pd
new_col = 'SampleText'
df = pd.read_csv('infile.csv', sep='|') # Read in the csv
df[new_col] = 0 # Insert the column at the end, and fill it with all 0's
df.columns = df.columns[:6].tolist()+[new_col]+df.columns[6:-1].tolist() # Reorder the columns, making sure not to use the last column twice because we wanted to reorder it.
df.to_csv('outfile.csv',index=False,sep='|') # Save your new csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to manage the delimiters yourself, just modify the list returned for each row.

Given:

```
RCLT_TYPE,RCLC_NM,RCLCF_DATA_SORC,RCLF_NM,RCLF_DATA_TYPE_NM,RCLF_GRPABLE_IND,RT_LOV_IND,MULTI_SEGMENTATION_IND,RT_FLTBL_IND,RT_FLD_FRMT,History/Current,Story
```

Then:

```
import csv

new_col = 'SampleText'
with open('infile.csv', 'r', newline='') as f:
    with open('outfile.csv', 'w', newline='') as output:
        reader = csv.reader(f) # No delimiter defined defaults to comma.
        writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter='|')
        for row in reader:  # row is a list of column items
            row.insert(7,new_col)  # add a column
            writer.writerow(row)  # writerow expects a list as a parameter.
```

Produces:

```
RCLT_TYPE|RCLC_NM|RCLCF_DATA_SORC|RCLF_NM|RCLF_DATA_TYPE_NM|RCLF_GRPABLE_IND|RT_LOV_IND|SampleText|MULTI_SEGMENTATION_IND|RT_FLTBL_IND|RT_FLD_FRMT|History/Current|Story
```